# Is it possible to dynamically add Conversation Drivers using items in a list?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I'd like to dynamically add some Conversation Drivers using items in a list, there may be 0 or more items up to 6.

A for-each loop is currently not allowed in the conversation-drivers block so I have resorted to using 'if' statements and selecting the corresponding item in the list.

```
conversation-drivers {
    if (size(this.options) > 0) {
      conversation-driver {
        template ("#{value(this.options[0].name)}")
      }
    }
    if (size(this.options) > 1) {
      conversation-driver {
        template ("#{value(this.options[1].name)}")
      }
    }
    if (size(this.options) > 2) {
      conversation-driver {
        template ("#{value(this.options[2].name)}")
      }
    }
}
```

This works but it's ugly, is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that there is no `for-each` child key inside `conversation-drivers`. Nice workaround with `if` and I'm afraid that's the way to go for now.

One note about `conversation-drivers`, it might not look pretty if more than 3 choices due to the mobile device screen size. You may want to check sample view with the 6 items first.

Have fun with Bixby!